# Unanswered questions with the most votes

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

If you look at the list of Unanswered questions and sort by number of votes, these two pop up first:

- [Clojure 1.2.1/1.3/1.4 'proxy generated in Grails 2.0.0 runtime fails. 1.2.0 is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9101969)
- [Process crashes during creation of RoboGuice injector, if there is a mocked instance in any module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6101310)

The first has 59 votes, and the second has 47, though both seem a list too esoteric to have garnered that many votes. In both cases, the asker has only one question (and zero answers).

Is this for real?

Comment: +1 to Community for offering a 500 bounty on these questions!

Answer (score 3):

What's there not to be real about it? Both questions are quite old (9 months and 1 year) and have obviously attracted a number of people (both about 1,000 views) who feel this is a real problem that shows effort and needs answered. It doesn't matter who posted it; the fact that both are from users whom have only asked one question and posted no answers is pure coincidence.

If you don't feel they are good questions, all I can say is feel free to downvote. There's really nothing else to talk about, unless there's something else that's bothering you.

Comment: I don't have any problem with the question whatsoever, and it doesn't bother me in the slightest. I simply found it peculiar. You have posted 52 questions on SO, several with over 1k views, and none have even a fourth as many upvotes. Yes, it's probably a coincidence, but it seems statistically improbable, and I was wondering if their might be an alternative hypothesis.

Comment: Well, the amount of upvotes it receives also depends on factors such as the topic, which users actually view the question, whether they came to the question out of interest or looking for an answer. Also, good questions which don't have an answer yet tend to attract more votes than those which already do. The *interest* factor plays in big there; people will upvote it because they find it interesting and nothing more. I've done it myself on a few occasions.